# Centralizar nav com Materializecss

Tags: css, nav-bar

Olá,

Estou realizando um laboratório com o uso do Materializecss, mas estou com dificuldades para centralizar o menu(nav) da página. Alguém pode ajudar?

Veja o link

http://www.equipasub.com.br/teste/

Obrigado.

Comment: Poste o código da página junto com o css dela

Comment: Acho que fica mais fácil para vc ver o problema na própria página com o erro http://www.equipasub.com.br/teste/ ...praticamente não tem alteração dos exemplos do site do materializecss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que eu vi na [documentação](http://materializecss.com/navbar.html), criei algumas classes:

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 769px){

   .nav-wrapper ul.center {
     display: block;
     width: auto;
   }

   .nav-wrapper > ul.center li {
     float: none;
     display: inline-block;
   }

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<nav>
<div class="nav-wrapper">
  <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
  <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
  <ul class="center hide-on-med-and-down">
    <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
    <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
    <li><a href="collapsible.html">Javascript</a></li>
    <li><a href="mobile.html">Mobile</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-demo" style="left: -250px;">
    <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
    <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
    <li><a href="collapsible.html">Javascript</a></li>
    <li><a href="mobile.html">Mobile</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
 </nav>
```

**Obs.:** Eu não tenho certeza se não ocasionou problema no menu mobile. Precisa testar pra averiguar.

Comment: Funcionou! Obrigado. Uma dúvida: Na sua opinião qual a melhor forma de colocar o logo no meio do menu?

Comment: Pelo que eu vi na documentação, já tem uma opção para deixar a logo centralizada, porém os links ficam nos cantos, tudo centralizado talvez seria colocar a logo no meio dos links @Rodney.

Comment: Era o que eu tinha em mente. Mais uma vez, obrigado!

Answer (score -2):

Tente diminuir somente o container do menu `nav-wrapper`:

```
nav .nav-wrapper { width:40% }
```